# When to be careful about multithreading in EJBs?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, ejb-3.0

I understand that App Server takes care of the threading so the developer should only concentrate on the business logic... 
but  consider an example. A stateless EJB has a member of type CountManager.

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class StatelessEJB {
  private CountManager countManager;
  ... 
  public void incrementCount() {countManager.incrementCount();}
  public int getCount(){return countManager.getCount();}
}
```

And the CountManager

```
 public class CountManager {
    public void increaseCount() {
    // read count from database
    // increase count 
    // save the new count in database table. 
    }

    public int getCount() {
    // returns the count value from database.
    }
}
```

The developer should think about multi-threading here. If you make CountManager also an EJB, I guess problem won't go away.
What would be the general guideline for developer to watch out for?

Update:
Changed the code. Assume that the methods of EJB are exposed as webservice, so we have no control what order client calls them. Transaction attribute is default. Does this code behave correctly under multi threaded scenario?

Comment: Describe why you say that "this code isn't thread safe". What operations are you executing, in what order and what results would you expect? Do you fear of EJB concurrency access or the concurrent database access? Are you using the default EJB `TransactionAttribute`s?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki updated the question, removed the statement you mentioned. I fear the results are incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that EJB are thread-safe doesn't mean that different methods invocations will give you consistent results.

EJB gives you the certainty that every method in your particular **EJB instance** will be executed by exactly **one thread**. This doesn't save you from multiple users accessing different instances of your EJB and inconsistent results dangers.

Your `CountManager` seems to be a regular Java class which means that you hold a state in Stateless EJB. This is not good and EJB thread-safety won't protect you from anything in such case. Your object can be accessed through **multiple EJB instances** at the same time.

Between your client's first method invocation `StatelessEJB.incrementCount()` (which starts a transaction - default `TransactionAttribute`) and the second client's method invocation  `StatelessEJB.getCount()` (which starts **new** transaction) many things might happen and the value of the `count` could be changed.

If you'd change it to be an EJB I don't think you'd be any more safe. If it's a SLSB than it still can't have any state. If the state is not realized as a EJB field variable but a database fetched data, than it's definitely better but still - the transaction is not a real help for you because your WebService client still executes these two methods separately therefore landing in two different transactions.

The simple solution would be to:

- use the database (no state in SLSB) which can be synchronized with your EJB transaction,
- execute both of these methods within the transaction (like `incrementAndGet(-)` method for WebService client).

Than you can be fairly sure that the results you get are consistent.

Comment: thanks, two things, your answer negates the answer of Lopez above. Right?
2nd, why do you thing that StatelessEJB has a state if has a variable of CountManager. The state is actually in database.Isn't it?

Comment: No, I don't think it negates Oscar's answer as he also talks about transactions and database importance and being a part in a transaction.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I didn't carefully read that your POJO is accessing the database and assumed that it holds the state within `CountManager`. It's fine to have a dependency injection-less POJO (at least if you instantiate it i.e. in constructor). The question is - how you're accessing the database and if this access will be EJB transaction-aware.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that is not really a problem of synchronization or multi-threading, but of transactional behavior.

The above code, if run inside an EJB, will take care of race conditions by delegating transaction support to the data base. Depending on the isolation level and transactional attributes, the data base can take care of locking the underlying tables to ensure that the information remains consistent, even in the face of concurrent access and/or modifications.